# Detect if mobile chrome's Data saving feature is enable from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile-chrome, chrome-datasaver

In mobile chrome on android device, there is a setting called "Data saving" accessible from Settings > Data saving.

When enabled the behavior can be slightly different when reading media, especially video: on mobile autoplay videos are prohibited except if the video is muted but if data saving is enable muted autoplay isn't allowed anymore.

I would need  a way to detect if data saving is used so I can change my video player behavior.

I know that there is a header sent in http requests: "save-data: on"
But I don't know any way to read http requests header from javascript.

More info here:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript to access headers in javascript

Comment: thanks but it concerns only response headers whereas my need is in request headers

Comment: @Guian did you ever find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript way to detect chrome data saver mode

```js
if('connection' in navigator){
 if(navigator.connection.saveData){
  console.log(`Your save data mode is = ${navigator.connection.saveData}`)
 }else{
  console.log(`Your save data mode is = ${navigator.connection.saveData}`)
 }
}
```

For more details follow google developer blog post on [Delivering fast and light applications with Save-Data](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/save-data/)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the user has turned on data saving mode in Chrome, Opera or Yandex by looking for a `save-data` request header. Dean Hume gives an example of how to [detect data saving mode](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/service-workers--save-your-users-data-using-the-save-data-header/10139), though unfortunately his example uses a service worker, so it won't work on Opera Mini.

Chrome Data Saver uses a proxy, as do some other Android browsers such as Opera Mini in Extreme mode and UC Browser Mini for Android in Speed Mode.

You should also be able to look for the `X-Forwarded-For` header to detect if the [Chrome Data Compression Proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression-for-isps#client-ip) is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a little solution to this. There is something with the ENV variable in PHP. I found out through some random debugging that there is a variable **HTTP_SAVE_DATA** in the env variable. So my code looks like this:

```
<?php
if ($_ENV["HTTP_SAVE_DATA"] == "on"){
  echo "Datasaver on"; 
}else{
  echo "Datasaver off"; 
}
?>
```

Hope it works for you :)

(you just have to echo this into an js variable and you can access it via js)

Comment: Is $_SERVER not $_ENV: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/save-data/#checking_for_save-data_in_server_side_code